# Ansible Galaxy keep SCM files

Tags: git, ansible, ansible-galaxy

I'm using the command:

```
ansible-galaxy install -r requirements.yml
```

where `requirements.yml` is:

```
- src: https://github.com/USERNAME/ANSIBLE-ROLE.git
  version: master
  scm: git
```

and it creates the directory: `/etc/ansible/roles/ANSIBLE-ROLE`

How I can keep the SCM files like the `.git` directory?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I guess your are out of luck here.
[This](https://github.com/ansible/ansible/blob/devel/lib/ansible/playbook/role/requirement.py#L179) is how things done: mkdir, clone, checkout, archive, rmtree.
Then required role is installed from temporary archive file.